# Unusually low cap on number of test users in Facebook

Tags: facebook, testing

I'm trying to set up test users using the "roles" tab in the facebook developer app but it is capping the number of test users I can add at 6 even though this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ link says that you can add up to 500!  When I try to add more by selecting 10 on the drop down menu it seems to be doing some processing but when it finishes nothing has been added.

Does anyone know why I am being capped at this number?

Comment: This seems like a question to email to facebook's api developers, or to post on the developer forums.

Comment: If the docs bluntly say you can have more, then this is probably a bug on their part and there's nothing SO can do to help. I agree with Wug's comment

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the help guys - feel free to close it if you want.  I thought it may have something to do with me being an amateur developer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook's interface for creating and managing test users is hell. [Get the free FacebookTestUserManager](http://fbtum.codeplex.com/) (Windows only) and save yourself the headache. It's less buggy than Facebook's web interface.

If you're on a mac, google around there are other standalone test user managers out there.